# Show $ \lim_{x \to 0}\left[\int_0^{1} by+a(1-y)^x\,dy \right]^\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{e}\left[\frac{b^b}{a^a}\right]^\frac{1}{b-a}$ for $a < b$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do we prove;
$$L =  \lim_{x \to 0}\left[\int_0^{1} by+a(1-y)^x\,dy \right]^\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{e}\left[\frac{b^b}{a^a}\right]^\frac{1}{b-a}, a < b$$

This question is from a test.

Let $\displaystyle V = \int_0^{1} by+a(1-y)^x\,dy$ then I used the substitution $by+a(1-y) = t$ to derive $V = \left[\dfrac{b^{x+1}-a^{x+1}}{(x+1)(b-a)}\right]$, from which,
$$L = \lim_{x \to 0}\left[\frac{b^{x+1}-a^{x+1}}{(x+1)(b-a)}\right]^\frac{1}{x}$$
Could anyone suggest how this limit can be evaluated (taking log on both sides did not get me the answer)

Comment: There's something wrong here: $c=\int_0^{1} by+a(1-y)\,dy$ doesn't depends on $x$ so $L=\lim_{x\to 0} c^{1/x}$ which equals $0$, $1$ or $\infty$

Comment: Please, recheck your equations. After your edit, still isn't right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $x\to 0^+$, let $t=b/a>1$
$$\begin{align}\left[\frac{b^{x+1}-a^{x+1}}{(x+1)(b-a)}\right]^\frac{1}{x}&=
\frac{a}{(1+x)^{1/x}}\exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(1+\frac{t}{t-1}(e^{x\ln(t)}-1)\right)\right)\\
&\sim \frac{a}{e}\exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(1+\frac{t\ln(t)}{t-1}x\right)\right)\\
&\to \frac{a}{e}\exp\left(\frac{t\ln(t)}{t-1}\right)=\frac{a}{e}t^{\frac{t}{t-1}}=\frac{1}{e}\left(\frac{b^b}{a^a}\right)^\frac{1}{b-a}
\end{align}$$
where we applied $e^{rx}-1\sim rx$ and $\ln(1+rx)\sim rx.$